# Second USB-Port does not work

Tags: 12.10, usb, sony

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Sony Vaio SVT and everything works fine, except for the second USB port. 
It seems that everything I put in does not connect.
I tried several pen drives and mice. 
All those items are working on the first USB port.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First check if everything is OK with your USB ports are listed?

```
lsusb
```

for more details you can use `-v` or `-vv`.

After, check you more information:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i usb
sudo dmidecode | grep -i usb
```